# Python pocketsphinx recognition from the microphone

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, redhat

I have installed and setup both pocketsphinx and sphinxbase packages in python.
I have also taken code of speech recognition for github and changed both data and mode directory as per requirement but still it is unable to stream by voice when I am trying to run it by "python test.py"
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sphinxbase as sb
import pocketsphinx as ps

MODELDIR = '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/pocketsphinx-data'
DATADIR='/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/pocketsphinx-data'
# Create a decoder with certain model
config = ps.Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/pocketsphinx-data/en-US/acoustic-model")
config.set_string('-lm', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-US/language-model.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-US/pronounciation-dictionary.dict'))
decoder = ps.Decoder(config)

# Decode streaming data.
decoder.start_utt()
stream = open(os.path.join(DATADIR, 'en-US/goforward.raw'), 'rb')
while True: 
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
stream.close()
print('Best hypothesis segments:', [seg.word for seg in decoder.seg()])
```

Please tell me how to execute it.

Comment: You need to provide the description of the problem you see

Comment: Actually, there is no exact problem on the terminal. It is printing all the details of the modules correctly but it is not streaming(taking any vice input) when I am trying to execute it.

Comment: For recording microphone you need to take pyaudio stream, you can find samples in sources

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Continuous recognition from microphone should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import environ, path
import pyaudio

from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "../../../model"

config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
decoder = Decoder(config)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream() 

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                print 'Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr
                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

Comment: When I run your code, I have this Error:
 `error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory`
  `ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx`

Comment: @mehdializade `swig` is a command required to build `pocketsphinx`. You should be able to install swig on Windows using the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7443112/16775594).

Comment: This code gives me large error messages when I run it; is there a Python 3 equivalent?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin wrap the print command in brackets.
`print ('Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr)`