# pycharm swig how to? [windows]

Tags: windows, pycharm, swig

I would require some guidance in regards to installing a module/package in pycharm (free edition). I have to mention that i have not worked with this IDE yet and wanted to try it out on a little project containing smartcards.

When i try to install "pyscard" i get the error that boils down to

> error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory

People say just install SWIG, which i guessed already ^^.
The issue i have is that i actually have no idea how to... and none of the pages i found has really enlightended me on this issue.

I downloaded the zip "swigwin-3.0.12" but i am at a loss what to do with it now. **EDIT:** According to the SWIG page this is an already compiled version and i have to somehow make pycharm recognize that the folder it is in contains the swig.exe it requires.

**EDIT2:** Adding the folder containing the swig.exe to the PATH variable also did not work ... which i thought would be the issue

**EDIT3+Answer:**
Ok the link in the comments from "wp78de" was correct my problem was that pycharm/pc restart were needed for it to catch the added PATH variable to the swig.exe (for pycharm that is)

Any advice is appriciated.

**Envoirment:**

Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

Pycharm 2017.2.4

Python 3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install SWIG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443112/how-to-install-swig)

Comment: yes i have seen that one already but the problem as far as i see it, is that i already get a compiled version of it , ergo i would not need to do that .. either way there is nothing in said folder that would interact with a configure command ... as far as i know i need to add the swig folder to pycharm somehow so it knows it is present ... and i have no clue how to do so

Comment: Have you looked at the second answer (with much more up votes than the accepted answer)? Basically, add swig.exe to your `%PATH%`.

Comment: yeah actually tried it .. did not work .. yet :/  ill see if i can run it from cmd like that or some stuff :)  EDIT:  ok CMD finds swig.exe whereever i run it from just pycharm does not want to -.- EDIT2: ok i restarted pycharm and my PC now it works and needs some other stuff but i should be able to handle that ... can you make a real answer so i can mark it as correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you just have to add the directory that contains the swig executable the [PATH environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them). You can do it via [CMD](https://superuser.com/questions/346681/is-the-set-command-equivalent-to-defining-an-environment-variable) or the [Windows UI](https://superuser.com/a/826657/748438).

If you have added swig to your path, you should be able to call it in the command prompt from any directory: open "cmd", and type `swig --help`" on that prompt.

A restart of PyCharm (or whatever your IDE is) and Windows might be required.